# Drawing on a screen with other views in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas, android-edittext, textview

I have been searching for the past few hours to the answer to a very dumb question. I know how to draw on the canvas in android if you extend the view class, modify onDraw and set setContentView() to a new instance of that class. However, I need to also have 2 TextViews and 2 EditTexts at the bottom of the activity and if setContentView() is set to only have that view, these views will, obviously, not display. How can put all of these on the screen?

EDIT: Here is my code: (the package name is android.physicsengine)

```
package android.physicsengine;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class ResultantForceEngine extends Activity {
private EditText mag;
private EditText dir;
private View image;
private RelativeLayout layout;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.resultant_force);

    mag = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.magnitude);
    dir = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.direction);
}

public class MyView extends View{
    public MyView(Context context){

        super(context);
    }
    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){

        super(context, attrs);

    }
    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle){

        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        Paint circlePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        circlePaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawLine(canvas.getWidth()/2, canvas.getHeight()/2-200, canvas.getWidth()/2 ,canvas.getHeight()/2+200, circlePaint);
        canvas.drawLine(canvas.getWidth()/2-200, canvas.getHeight()/2, canvas.getWidth()/2+200 ,canvas.getHeight()/2, circlePaint);
    }
}
}
```

and the xml

```
<view class="android.physicsengine.ResultantForceEngine$MyView"
              android:id="@+id/image"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
              android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
              android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
<TextView     android:id="@+id/magText"
              android:text="Magnitude (N) ="
              android:textSize="15dip"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:padding="3dip"
              android:gravity="center_vertical" 
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    <EditText android:id="@+id/magnitude"
              android:inputType="numberDecimal"
              android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
              android:layout_toRightOf ="@id/magText"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:padding="3dip"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/dirText"
              android:text="Angle (deg) ="
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:textSize="15dip"
              android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
              android:layout_toRightOf ="@id/magnitude"
              android:padding="3dip"
              android:gravity="center_vertical" />
    <EditText android:id="@+id/direction"
              android:inputType="numberDecimal"
              android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
              android:layout_toRightOf ="@id/dirText"
              android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:padding="3dip"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you need to define your XML file with your custom view class and the other widgets you have.  In your case, there would be the custom view, 2 textviews and 2 edittexts in the XML file.

You define the custom view in XML just like any other widget, except you use the namespace of the view and the class name.

```
<com.example.android.myCustomView
    android:id="@+id/my_custom_view"
    ...
```

Then inside your activity a simple call

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Edit:  The problem is your class is private, so it "isn't seen" when your activity makes a call the layout and tries to inflate it.

Edit2:  Of course this won't work, you're using an inner class!  You have to communicate stuff like this if you expect to get answers.

The XML syntax for an inner class is different.

```
<view class="com.example.android.MyClass$MyInnerClass"
```

Comment: I tried this and I received a runtime xml parsing error. I am positive i spelled everything correctly. I will add that code above.

Comment: Tom, your custom view needs to have a special constructor made public so that the LayoutInflater can create an instance of your custom view. Your customView class needs to have the ctor shown at http://d.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#View(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) . An example implementation is available at http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/LabelView.html

Comment: I'm sorry if Im mistaken, but isnt that constructor just
public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){

        super(context, attrs);

    }
like I have above?

Comment: there are 2 errors: Binary xml file line 7: Error inflating the class android.physicsengine.ResultantForceEngine.MyView and ClassNotFoundException for android.physicsengine.ResultantForceEngine.MyView

Comment: Is "ResultantForceEngine" a package or a class within the android.physicsengine package?  If it is a class, you need to change your XML file to <android.physicsengine.MyView

Comment: It is the activity file that contains MyView. I will try what you said though.

Comment: The same errors came up when i tried that. Thanks for the attempt though.

Comment: I changed the class to public and it still comes up with the same two errors.

Comment: Im sorry. I completely forgot to mention that. However, Im still getting the same errors with that change. I will edit my code to reflect how it currently stands.

Comment: I got ti to work by pulling the inner class out into its own file and using your first suggestion. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the class that you extended in your res/layout/main.xml just like you would any other View class, and add your TextView and EditTexts in the layout .xml file like normal. I have not personally done this, but I have used custom View classes in this way.

Then for your setContentView you would just use the layout .xml file like:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            ...
```